# Getting a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to launch a mapactivity via intent

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm new to the Map View implementation in Android. I'm trying to launch a new Activity (on a button click) that will contain the google maps. I seem to be doing everything mentioned in http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html. However i'm getting the following error:-

```
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 11 more
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.sam.LocationActivity
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at org.sam.SelfDefActivity.showLocator(SelfDefActivity.java:16)
04-18 12:11:11.332: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 14 more
```

This is what method showLocator looks like:-

```
public void showLocator(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SelfDefActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
    final int result=1;
    startActivityForResult(i, result);
    finish();
}
```

This is what my manifest looks like:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.sam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SelfDefActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/location_activity" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Could anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: your class `LocationActivity` in the package `org.sam` or not, suggestion using full class name in your xml like ` android:name="com.xxx.LocationActivity"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add full path for your activity in manifest file

like `android:name="your package name.LocationActivity"`

As your activity name suggest you are checking location your should add permission for that also as below

Your manifest should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.sam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SelfDefActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/location_activity" >   
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you tri this type

```
</application>
         <activity
          ......
          .....

         </activity>

 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>
```